# How to sort on embedded entity's property using Pageable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an entity embedded into another as shown below.
The repository is created on the `DepEntity`.
I am trying retrieve the `DepEntity` objects sorted on `totalExp` column
in `ExpEntity`.
I m making a GET call using Pageable and getting the error:

> 2018-12-18 05:17:58.172  WARN 7 --- [http-nio-8000-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property totalExp found for type DepEntity!]

I tried with `totalExp`, `exp.totalExp` and `exp_totalExp` and none of them worked. The spring data jpa version is 2.1.1

```
@Entity
public class DepEntity {
    @Embedded
    private ExpEntity exp;
}

@Embeddable
public class ExpEntity {
    @Column(name = "exp_total")
    private BigDecimal totalExp;
}
```

I expect the results in sorted order on the nested property `totalExp`.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Below should work:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("exp.totalExp").descending();
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
Page<DepEntity> depEntities  = depEntityRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
```